# center and align item within enumerate latex

Tags: latex

I would like to align my equations for nicely in latex. My problem is that those equations represent conditions with that they need to be numerated. What I have now numerates my equation but my first equation is not align with the others. Any suggestion?

```
\begin{center}
\begin{enumerate}
\centering
\item $f_k(x_k)=y_k$
\item $f_k(x_{k+1})=f_{k+1}(x_{k+1})$
\item $f^\prime_k(x_{k+1})=f^\prime_{k+1}(x_{k+1})$
\item $f^{\prime\prime}_k(x_{k+1})=f^{\prime\prime}_{k+1}(x_{k+1})$
\end{enumerate}
\end{center}
```

> Blockquote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello you may use a minipage and delete the \centering.
I also added the \fbox just to see the borders of the minipage, you may take it out if you wish.

```
\begin{center}
\fbox{
\begin{minipage}{2in}
\begin{enumerate}
\item $f_k(x_k)=y_k$
\item $f_k(x_{k+1})=f_{k+1}(x_{k+1})$
\item $f^\prime_k(x_{k+1})=f^\prime_{k+1}(x_{k+1})$
\item $f^{\prime\prime}_k(x_{k+1})=f^{\prime\prime}_{k+1}(x_{k+1})$
\end{enumerate}
\end{minipage}
}
\end{center}
```